# joomla integrate dynamic php pages to project

Tags: php, url, dynamic, joomla

I am trying to integrate to a joomla project, a list of php pages setup that update their content from db, and give select options to the user, to navigate through this content. Select is also dynamic. All dynamic features work with url parsing.

For example, pageone.php gets some data from db and creates a list of selectable links to page2.php?data=fetcheddata. Page 2 gets url variables and performs queries to db to select the data.

How am I going to integrate this to Joomla? Should I make a module to include the basic php page, and how url parsing will then work? Should I make an i-frame wrapper? Please enlighten me..

Answer (score 0):

You just described the way Joomla works. Depending on the content you want to present, there may already be an extension that does that, or at least does something close that can be modified. Without any more details it is hard to say, but what you are describing could probably be accomplished with a CCK http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction. You could definitely do it with a combination of Chronoforms and Chrono Connectivity -
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/faq/5661

If not, then you will probably need to code a component - http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

Answer (score 0):

1) iframe solution is the easiest one. But it has its limitations...

2) you can write Joomla component (not a module) that will do the job, but I'm afraid in this case you will either have to switch to Joomla URL format... unless you find some trick how to workaround that.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is not very complex a simple approach is to write your application in plain php, and integrate your Joomla template to your application so your visitors can't tell any difference. Then, you will place links from your Joomla to your application and vice-versa accordingly.

However, the best approach if you are more familiar with Joomla is to develop a component. [Here](http://www.ultijoomla.com/blog/Joomla-Components-Modules-and-Plugins.html) you can understand the difference between Joomla Components, Modules and Plugins. Please read Joomla documentation for further understanding:
http://docs.joomla.org/Extension
http://docs.joomla.org/Component